# Parallel mergesort with parallel merge

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing, mergesort

how can I make a parallel mergesort with parallel merge? I didn't found any pseudocode on internet,I know only how to parallelize the first part of mergesort by spawn two thread for left and right,but how can I parallelize the merge? This is the code of the merge I need to parallelize.

```
public static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right, int[] array) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (i < left.length && j < right.length) {
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
            array[k] = left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            array[k] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < left.length) {
        array[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < right.length) {
        array[k] = right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    return array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from [this](http://dzmitryhuba.blogspot.com.tr/2010/10/parallel-merge-sort.html) I've tried to implement a parallel version of your code. Basic idea is to divide the problem into pieces and work on each piece in another task. I didn't tested it, might have bugs.

```
        public static int[] MergePll(int[] left, int[] right)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[left.Length + right.Length];
            int maxProcessCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 8;
            int leftPiece = Math.Max(1, left.Length / maxProcessCount);
            int rightPiece = Math.Max(1, right.Length / maxProcessCount);
            Parallel.For(0, maxProcessCount, (i) =>
            {
                int leftStart = leftPiece * i;
                int leftEnd = Math.Min(left.Length, leftStart + leftPiece);
                int rightStart = rightPiece * i;
                int rightEnd = Math.Min(right.Length, rightStart + rightPiece);
                int start = leftPiece * i + rightPiece * i;
                _merge(left, right, leftStart, leftEnd, rightStart, rightEnd, arr, start);
            });
            return arr;
        }
        private static void _merge(int[] left, int[] right, int leftStart, int leftEnd, int rightStart, int rightEnd, int[] arr, int start)
        {            
            while (leftStart < leftEnd && rightStart < rightEnd)
                if (left[leftStart] <= right[rightStart])
                    arr[start++] = left[leftStart++];
                else
                    arr[start++] = right[rightStart++];
            while (leftStart < leftEnd)
                arr[start++] = left[leftStart++];
            while (rightStart < rightEnd)
                arr[start++] = right[rightStart++];
        }
```

Edit: This is incomplete, would only work with data like "1,3,5,7"-"2,4,6,8" I'll try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to split up the array into k parts for k threads, do k merge sorts in parallel, then merge the k parts. For example, with 4 threads, 4 merge sorts are done in parallel, using for example threads 0, 1, 2, 3. Thread 1 and 3 just terminate after merge sort. After thread 2 does it's merge sort, it waits for thread 3 to terminate, merges the sorted parts from thread 2 and 3, and terminates. After thread 0 does it's merge sort, it waits for thread 1 to terminate, merges the parts from thread 0 and 1, waits for thread 2 to terminate, merges the sorted half from thread 0 with the sorted half from thread 2. In a test program I wrote, I allocated the second working array before starting the threads. The initial 1/4 array thread sorts end up with the sorted 1/4 parts back in the original array, the 1/4 + 1/4 merges end up with the sorted data in the working array, and the final 1/2 + 1/2 merge ends up back in the original array.